# Getting stored Json query from database and extracting only the values i want

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Currently iam working on a dashboard where i have to get stored JSON query's from the database and then select only select the keys i want to use. Iam working with laravel and Vuex.

Currently my controller looks like this.

```
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $log = Log::all();
        return (json_encode($log));
    }
```

At the moment this returns the table that i want and I'am able to select the column i want.

This is how my HTML looks

```
              <tr v-for="log in logs" :key="log.APIGROUPNO">
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6 lg:pl-8">{{ log.APIGROUPNO }}</td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.DATETIMEEXECUTED }}</td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.JSONBDY }}</td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.RESPONSE }}</td>
                <td class="relative whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6 lg:pr-8">
                  <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"
                  >Edit<span class="sr-only">, {{ log.APIGROUPNO }}</span></a
                  >
                </td>
              </tr>
```

The following code gives me this result.
[image: Current result]

What i would like to get back is the following:
[image: Desired result]

How would i be able to fix this, i have searched far and wide on the internet but cant seem to find a fitting solution. Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your code, I see 5 columns, but in your images i see only 3 columns. is it what you expect?

Comment: Yess that is expected. JSONBDY is missing because iam having the same problem with that column only that response is huge. The "Result" query is more oversee able

Comment: ok so just replace {{ log.RESPONSE }} with {{ log.RESPONSE["Result"][0]["ERRORS"] }}. tell me if it works, so i can make an answer with more detail, because you should also check that the array is not empty.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your quick response. I've tried your solution and i get back the following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: log.RESPONSE.Result is undefined.

Comment: can you please execute dd(json_encode($log)) before the return and post the result?

Comment: Please notice that there are keys with a simple first letter `result`. If the first element has `result` as the key `Result` will be undefined. Also note that `log.RESPONSE["Result"][0]["ERRORS"]` would give you a string similar to "65656: Weborder no does not exist :43434". You would need to extract the message you want from this string

Comment: @Mike Hi Mike i changed the Log::all() to Log::get('Response') because of sensitive info. The result i get is the full json response of the RESULT column. I'am not able to add an image to my reply sadly. But all the individual "rows" are separated by a comma in the JSON response.

Comment: @user3532758 The thing is when applying this i don't get anything back at all. The string you typed out is what iam looking for to get :) I now get them back as a json query but would like that to be just plain text

Comment: try this `log.RESPONSE["Result"]?.[0]["ERRORS"]`

Comment: @user3532758 Thank you for your response, i now seem to get a new error that says "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: log.RESPONSE is null". Could it be that it doesnt get recognized as a JSON query? Thanks in advance